# selenium webdriver manager update - npm

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, gruntjs, protractor, webdriver-manager

I tried to update the selenium webdriver using the "webdriver-manager", but i get the error as,

```
Error: Got error Error: read ECONNRESET from https://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/2.48/selenium-server-standalone-2.48.2.jar
Error: Got error Error: read ECONNRESET from https://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/2.48/selenium-server-standalone-2.48.2.jar
fs.js:60
      throw err;  // Forgot a callback but don't know where? Use NODE_DEBUG=fs
      ^

Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'C:\Users\user_name\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\selenium\selenium-server-standalone-2.48.2.jar'
    at Error (native)
```

I am not sure what was the cause. I tried updating the protractor too, but no luck.

Also i tried running the command prompt as administrator and run

```
webdriver-manager update --ignore_ssl
```

Please help.

Comment: Could you try manually downloading https://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/2.48/selenium-server-standalone-2.48.2.jar ? It looks like some firewall/dns/whatever network error.

Comment: @cvakiitho yes, it is a firewall problem. Can you let me know how can we download from http site instead of https? where can i change this config in selenium update?

Answer (score 2):

I have solved the issue as below,

```
// Update chrome alone
    webdriver-manager update --standalone=0 --chrome --alternate_cdn http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/

// Update selenium alone
    webdriver-manager update --chrome=0 --standalone --alternate_cdn http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/
```

Comment: I know this is late. But lemme ask this, I tried to use the --alternate_cdn to fetch the selenium-server-standalone jar from our artifactorywhich is a private repository of our organization. But each time I see this error:

Comment: I/config_source - curl -ok C:\protractor-cucumber\node_modules\webdriver-manager\selenium\gecko-response.json https://api.github.com/repos/mozilla/geckodriver/releases
events.js:167
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^
Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND api.github.com api.github.com:443

Comment: I appreciate any help.

Comment: @HarishaKP what was the issue you have?

Comment: Can you please check my issue here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/59395170/2613428

Answer (score 1):

I was facing same issue and got the below error when running update chrome driver.
Error: Got error Error: self signed certificate in certificate chain from https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.21/chromedriver_win32.zip
I manually downloaded the driver saved it as node_modules\protractor\selenium\chromedriver_2.21.exe 
and it worked. I was running it from my office network

Answer (score 0):

it actually works over http as well: http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/2.48/selenium-server-standalone-2.48.2.jar , just find-replace it inside the library.

Or download it manually to: node_modules/protractor/selenium

Comment: Thanks. yes it works over http. i have added alternate_cdn to the command of update webdriver-manager. But how to add two alterante cdn urls in th webdriver-manager update command. one url for chrome driver and another for selenium standalone?

Comment: webdriver-manager update is "only" downloading latest files, since you are already doing it manually, isn't it better to download selenium, and chromedriver manually, if you have to update urls for every single one?

If you want you can update it in bin/webdriver-manager

Answer (score 0):

i had same problem.

Solution for me was updating node.js (best way to do it - just download latest version and install it).