# webdriver manager not working behind proxy

Tags: selenium, proxy, webdriver-manager

I need to use webdriver-manager to execute:

```
 webdriver-manager update --proxy=https://proxy.company.com:8080
```

But get

```
webdriver-manager: using local installed version 12.0.6
events.js:160
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: read ECONNRESET
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:1020:11)
    at TLSWrap.onread (net.js:568:26)
```

i.e. the proxy command still does not seem to work for 12.0.6 for me.

Comment: May be the proxy doesn't work fine? Try this `NODE_DEBUG=cluster,net,http,fs,tls,module webdriver-manager update --proy=https://proxy.company.com:8080` and see if you see any logs

Comment: Unfortunately, this will not display any more logs than already seen above

Comment: Also I notice you have type `proy` instead of `proxy`. I hope that was just a typo will pasting?

Comment: No that is not the problem https://github.com/angular/webdriver-manager/issues/264#issuecomment-328556924

Answer (score 3):

What worked for me was adding --ignore_ssl in addition to --proxy

```
webdriver-manager update --proxy=http://someproxy:8080 --ignore_ssl
```

Comment: Yes, you can get it here: https://github.com/angular/webdriver-manager

Answer (score 1):

As question title sounds if-you want to use webDriver manager being behind proxy then use it like below in your browser instantiation class-

WebDriverManager.chromedriver().proxy("YourProxyServerUrl:YourPort").setup();

driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions-if you have);

And if you looking for:updating the selenium webdriver using the "webdriver-manager
Refer below thread -
[selenium webdriver manager update - npm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34719096/selenium-webdriver-manager-update-npm)

Comment: Thanks, this resolved one of my problem but I'm facing same issue with other dependencies too for ex- Cucumber Reports[masterthought one] and javax.mail for Sending email ..what to do?

Comment: You can Configure maven proxy urls in settings.xml as per your proxy needs. This file is  located in the maven installation 'conf' folder.

Comment: When you have a proxy url that contains a username/password, I bet this solution will not work.   For example, by default Java ignores Basic auth on proxy tunneling.  But still, I think this answer needs more evidence.    Also, the question was Javascript based, not Java.