# webdriver-manager update with --alternate_cdn argument

Tags: protractor, webdriver-manager

I want to do the below in my protractor-cucumber framework. I can not use public repo like googleapi.com as per org policy:

```
webdriver-manager update --standalone=0 --chrome --alternate_cdn https://www.artifactrepository.xyz.net/artifactory/api/npm-teamdev/
```

Also this:

```
webdriver-manager update --chrome=0 --standalone --alternate_cdn https://www.artifactrepository.xyz.net/artifactory/api/npm-teamdev/
```

But i always get this as response:

> C:\Users\ABCD\Desktop\JSProjects\protractor-cucumber>webdriver-manager
>   update --standalone=0 --chrome --alternate_cdn
>   https://www.artifactrepository.xyz.net/artifactory/api/npm/npm-teamdev/
>   curl -o
>   C:\Users\ABCD\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\webdriver-manager\downloads\chromedriver.xml
>   https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/ curl
>   https://api.github.com/rate_limit -H "User-Agent:
>   angular/webdriver-manager" [ERROR]:  { Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND
>   api.github.com api.github.com:443
>       at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:57:26)   errno: 'ENOTFOUND',   code: 'ENOTFOUND',   syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
>   hostname: 'api.github.com',   host: 'api.github.com',   port: 443 }
>   (node:8016) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot
>   convert undefined or null to object
>       at Function.keys ()
>       at getVersionObjs (C:\Users\ABCD\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\webdriver-manager\dist\lib\provider\utils\version_list.js:28:41)
>       at Object.getVersion (C:\Users\ABCD\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\webdriver-manager\dist\lib\provider\utils\version_list.js:12:25)
>       at GeckoDriver.updateBinary (C:\Users\ABCD\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\webdriver-manager\dist\lib\provider\geckodriver.js:62:43)
>       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7) (node:8016) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise
>   rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async
>   function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was
>   not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1) (node:8016) [DEP0018]
>   DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In
>   the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the
>   Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

I have also tried to modify the cdn url in ./node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/config.json

```
{
  "cdnUrls": {
    "selenium": "https://www.artifactrepository.xyz.net/artifactory/api/npm/npm-teamdev/",
    "chromedriver": "https://www.artifactrepository.xyz.net/artifactory/api/npm/npm-teamdev/",
    "geckodriver": "https://www.artifactrepository.xyz.net/artifactory/api/npm/npm-teamdev/",
    "iedriver": "https://www.artifactrepository.xyz.net/artifactory/api/npm/npm-teamdev/"
  }
}
```

This one also did not work for me. I got the same error.

- I want to know what's the issue here and how can how to resolve it?
- Does webdriver-manager expect xml when the request hits custom CDN url?
- If yes, is there a way to update if it returns html instead of xml. Because I can see all these drivers in the repo.

Comment: npm set chromedriver_cdnurl "https://www.artifactrepository.xyz.net/artifactory/api/npm/npm-teamdev/"

Comment: I still get the same error. I think webdriver-manager is looking for xml when it hits the cdn url but it gets html instead of xml. May be that's why I get this error. Do you have any suggestion anything if this is the case..

Comment: alternate_cdn is a flag that existed but the feature was removed. The flag remained but also should have been removed in version 12. It was removed in the next version of webdriver-manager

Comment: Thanks for the information. it's helpful.